# C quick sort function keeps crashing

Tags: c, function, quicksort

Part of an assignment I'm doing for school involved building a quick sort to sort an array. I'm pretty sure I have it close, however whenever I call it, it crashes on me

```
void quickSort(double * array, unsigned int size, int start, int stop)
{
    int swapIndex = start;
    int pivot = start;
    double temp;
    if (size > 1)
    {
        for (int i = pivot + 1; i < stop; ++i)
        {
            if (array[pivot] > array[i])
            {
                ++swapIndex;
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[swapIndex];
                array[swapIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
        temp = array[swapIndex];
        array[swapIndex] = array[pivot];
        array[pivot] = temp;
        quickSort(array, size, start, swapIndex);
        quickSort(array, size, swapIndex, size);
    }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/Ccv4KP3j

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: `quickSort(array, size, swapIndex, size - swapIndex`)?

Comment: `quickSort(array, size, start, swapIndex);..if (size > 1)` never end call itself. (same size)

Comment: It says that there's a stack overflow right at the start of the function. Could that mean that the recursion runs infinitely for some reason?

Comment: @WeatherVane would I be changing that for the first or second call?

Comment: My above comment is prob incorrect, but those two recursive lines are both wrong. They are not of size `size`. The *sum* of each of their sizes should be `size`.

Comment: @Frankjoww You need to get rid of the `size` parameter and then rethink your algorithm. The `start` and `stop` values are all you need. For example, the first `if` should be `if (start >= stop) return;`

Comment: I updated with a pastebin link to my current build of the function, now it returns an array in the exact same order i sent it

Comment: Start with trying to sort a zero-element array. Does it work? Now sort a one-element array. Does it work? A debugger will help.

Comment: Presumably you don't want to be swapping any elements outside the range `0` to `size-1` - otherwise the result will potentially be a crash.   But that relies on `start` and `stop` being suitably bounded, to prevent `i` or `swapIndex` going out of range.   Your code does nothing to ensure `start` and `stop` remain suitably bounded.

Answer (score 0):

**N.B.** This answer's based off the pastebin link as of 27/2/2016

First of all your function has the wrong return type - quicksort works in-place, meaning that it doesn't create any new arrays; it sorts the array you passed to it. It will work perfectly as a `void` function.

Remember that in C, arrays can only be passed *by reference*, i.e. every recursive call to `quicksort` deals with exactly the same array.

Your quicksort should work like so:

```
double arr[] = {12, -2, 4, 5, 2, 1};
quicksort(arr, 0, 5);
// arr is now sorted

int i;
for (i=0; i<6; i++){
    printf("%f, ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");
// prints "-2, 1, 2, 4, 5, 12"
```

For the sake of clarity, I'd recommend writing a function void `doubleSwap(double *a, double* b)` to take care of all the element swapping without muddying your code.

The reason your code results in stack overflows is twofold:

1. The initial `if` guard needs to check if start and stop differ by
   more than one, not just if they're different.
2. The 'swapIndex' variable always overlaps the pivot cell, resulting in
   confusion as the pivot value gets mutated before the
   whole array is processed. It can be fixed by setting `pivot` to
   `stop - 1`.

Here is a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tQG0tKdn) of my version of your code, but before looking at it, try to debug it yourself using a bunch of `printf`s.

Also note that you don't have to pass the whole array to qsort - you can replace `quickSort(array, swapIndex, stop)` with `quickSort(array + swapIndex, 0, stop - swapIndex)`, allowing you to get rid of `start` altogether because it's always zero.

```
void doubleSwap(double *a, double*b){
    double temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

void quickSort(double * array, int start, int stop)
{
    int pivot = stop - 1;
    int swapIndex = start;
    int i;

    if (start < stop - 1) {
        for (i = start; i < stop; i++) {
            if (array[i] < array[pivot]){
                doubleSwap(array + swapIndex, array + i);
                swapIndex++;
            }
        }

        // Note that `array + swapIndex` is equivalent to `&(array[swapIndex])`
        doubleSwap(array + swapIndex, array + pivot);

        fprintf(stderr, "swapIndex = %d start = %d stop = %d\n", swapIndex, start, stop);
        for (i = 0; i< NELEMS; i++){
            fprintf(stderr, "%3f, ", array[i]);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");

        quickSort(array, start, swapIndex);
        quickSort(array, swapIndex, stop);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pastebins expire... :(

Comment: @Seb I set this one to never expire, but I'll add it to my answer anyway